# If a string contains a suffix from a list, how do I strip that specific suffix from the string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, stemming

I have a list of strings and a list of suffixes. If a string contains one of the suffixes, how do I strip that specific one from the string?

```
b = ["food", "stuffing", "hobbitses"]
y = ["ing", "es", "s", "ly"]


def stemming():
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i].endswith(tuple(y)):
            b[i] = b[i] - #???
print b
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend separating out the stem removal into its own function, and then using a list comprehension or a separate function for the whole list.  Here's one way of doing it

```
def remove_stems(word, stems):
    for stem in stems:
        if word.endswith(stem):
            return word[:-len(stem)]
        else: 
            return word

b_without_stems = [remove_stem(word, stems) for word in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want to strip the first suffix found this will do it

```
def stemming(strings, endings):
    for i, string in enumerate(strings):
        for ending in endings:
            if string.endswith(ending):
                strings[i] = string[:-len(ending)]
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which ending has been found, so you need to check them one at a time instead of trying to check them all at once. Once you have found an ending, you can chop it off using a slice.

```
def stemming():
    for i, word in enumerate(b):
        for suffix in y:
            if word.endswith(suffix):
                b[i] = word[:-len(suffix)]
                break
```

A better approach would use a regular expression:

```
import re
suffix = re.compile("(%s)$" % "|".join(y))

def stemming():
    for i, word in enumerate(b):
        b[i] = suffix.sub("", word)
```

Then you can easily do the stemming using a list comprehension:

```
b = [suffix.sub("", w) for w in b]
```